# How to perform reference a window function inside current table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, dataexplorer

I have this part in a larger query which consume lot of RAM:

```
TopPerPost as
(
   select Id,
      CloseReasonTypeId,
      Name,
      ReasonsPerPost.TotalByCloseReason,
      row_number() over(partition by Id order by TotalByCloseReason desc) seq -- Get the most common Id (The most common close Reason)
   from ReasonsPerPost
   where Name is NOT NULL and TopPerPost.seq=1 -- Remove useless results here, instead of doing it later
)
```

but I got The multi-part identifier "TopPerPost.seq" could not be bound.
Last detail... I only Use the`Name`column in a later`INNER JOIN`of that table.

Comment: If you change `TopPerPost.seq=1` to `seq=1` what happens?

Comment: @entropic :`Invalid column name 'seq'`. Whereas I use TopPerPost.seq=1 later in the query.

Comment: Then I think you have to let it evaluate first by wrapping it in a CTE and filter immediately after that or doing `select * from (select .., row_number().. from) where seq = 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a window function in the where of the same query. Just create a second cte.

```
with TopPerPost as
(
   select Id,
      CloseReasonTypeId,
      Name,
      ReasonsPerPost.TotalByCloseReason,
      row_number() over(partition by Id order by TotalByCloseReason desc) seq -- Get the most common Id
   from ReasonsPerPost
   where Name is NOT NULL 
)
, OnlyTheTop as
(
    select *
    from TopPerPost
    where seq = 1
)
```

Or you can do it like this.

```
select * from 
(
   select Id,
      CloseReasonTypeId,
      Name,
      ReasonsPerPost.TotalByCloseReason,
      row_number() over(partition by Id order by TotalByCloseReason desc) seq -- Get the most common Id
   from ReasonsPerPost
   where Name is NOT NULL 
) s
where seq = 1
```

Here is another option that should eliminate the need for so many rows being returned.

```
select Id,
      CloseReasonTypeId,
      Name,
      s.TotalByCloseReason
   from ReasonsPerPost rpp
   cross apply
   (
        select top 1 TotalByCloseReason
        from ReasonsPerPost rpp2
        where rpp2.Id = rpp.Id
        order by TotalByCloseReason desc
   ) s
   where Name is NOT NULL
```

Attempt #4...this would be a LOT easier with a sql fiddle to work with.

```
select Id,
      CloseReasonTypeId,
      Name,
      s.TotalByCloseReason
   from ReasonsPerPost rpp
   inner join
   (
        select top 1 TotalByCloseReason
        from ReasonsPerPost rpp2
        where rpp2.Id = rpp.Id
        and Name is NOT NULL
        order by TotalByCloseReason desc
   ) s on s.Id = rpp.Id
   where Name is NOT NULL
```

Comment: Lean : Yes, but that subquery produce a very large amount of useless results. Of course I already known how to it later but the subquery result are stored in RAM and I would cut the number of intermediates rows usage twice If I would achieve the where close. Currently I am not able to perform the query with the full results.

Comment: @user2284570 I added another option that might work in your case.

Comment: Yes, but in my case, removing `Name is NOT NULL`for keeping `seq = 1`is far worst.

Comment: I believe the third option will give more than one row for the same id, where as the the previous ones will give only one.

Comment: @SurendraNathGM : Currently `seq`three possible values : 1; 2; and 3. Only ~5,200 Rows have this result *(a very small percentage)*. and the ration beetween `seq=1`and `seq=2`looks equal. But in all cases, keeping null values makes a very larger subquery.

Comment: @user2284570 I posted one more attempt. This is really tough with not ddl to work with. Just tossing queries in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

The below might work for your need.
But without looking at the data is hard to tell it will or not.

```
;with t as
(
  Select Id, max(totalbyclosereason) TC from reasonsperpost where name is not null group by id
)
Select T.id,t.tc,c.closereasontypeid,c.name 
From t join reasonsperpost c on t.id = c.id and t.tc = c.totalbyclosereason
```

Comment: Ok for the kind of data... just all the closes votes of Stack exchange. Just look at the tags.

Comment: Did the above query work or did you get some thing wrong

Comment: I'm trying it (lot of SWAPS). If it work, it would have take times. + I updated the question.

Comment: No, some Rows are near duplicates *(Seq=1 is here to avoid it)*. I'm rolled back to last revision.